# How to identify per post images from separate image's table in php mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In this PHP script I have a multipart data form like if I submit form input text data insert to separate table and image files insert to an other separate table.
After submitting I was get total image related user id now related per post so I want how to get per post's separate related images.

Database tables diagram here:

[image: Database tables diagram here]

Comment: little but still thinking about how to attach images with related post

Comment: pls post what you have done

Comment: ?? I cant figure out what is your expected output..your requirement is not clear..thats why I mentioned to show what you did

Comment: i want to if i submit button to get "post_article_table" id in image_table?

Comment: is it for a particular post_id?

Comment: are you talking about 'selecting the images from database related to the post article' or 'inserting the post article id in image_table on clicking submit button'?which one?

Comment: after submitting data i fetch images with related post.

Comment: yes affaz ur correct

Comment: yes i need this

Comment: which one..the first one i mentioned..or the second?

Comment: are you talking about 'selecting the images from database related to the post article' or 'inserting the post article id in image_table on clicking submit button'? this one

Comment: i have mentioned 2 different topics in it..which one did you mean?the select case or insert case??